# Using dynamic typing in D, a statically typed language

Tags: d, dynamic-typing

I was implementing a dynamic typing library for D when I ran across an interesting problem.

Right now, I've succeeded in making a function called `dynamic()` which returns a dynamic version of an object.

For example:

```
import std.stdio, std.dynamic.core;

class Foo
{
    string bar(string a) { return a ~ "OMG"; }
    int opUnary(string s)() if (s == "-") { return 0; }
}

void main(string[] argv)
{
    Dynamic d = dynamic(new Foo());
    Dynamic result = d.bar("hi");
    writeln(result);  // Uh-oh
}
```

The problem I've run across is the fact that `writeln` tries to use *compile-time* reflection to figure out how to treat `result`.

What's the first thing it tries?  `isInputRange!(typeof(result))`

The trouble is, it returns **true**! Why? Because I have to assume that all members which it needs exist, unless I can prove otherwise at run time  -- which is too late. So the program tries to call `front`, `popFront`, and `empty` on `result`, crashing my program.

I can't think of a way to fix this. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to make two fundamentally different concepts work together, namely templates and dynamic typing. Templates rely very much on static typing, isInputRange works by checking which attributes or methods a type has. Your dynamic type  is treated as having every attribute or method at compile time, ergo it is treated as fulfilling *every* static duck-typing interface.
Therefore, to make Dynamic work in a statically typed environment, you have to provide more static information at some places.

Some solutions I can see:

1. provide your own dynamically typed implementations for heavily used functions. The whole problem you are having is caused by the fact that you are trying to use generic functions that assume static typing with dynamic types.
2. explicitly make dynamic a range of char, and care for the conversion to string of the underlying data yourself. (You'd have to have a custom toString method anyways if the isInputRange issue would not exist, because otherwise its result would again be of Dynamic type). This would probably make writeln(d); work.
3. provide wrappers for dynamic that allow you to pass dynamic types into various templated functions. (Those would just exhibit a static interface and forward all calls to Dynamic).

Eg:

```
Dynamic d;
// wrap d to turn it into a compile-time input range (but NOT eg a forward range)
Dynamic d2=dynamic(map!q{a*2}(dynInputRange(d))); 
// profit
```

4 . Add a member template to Dynamic, which allows to statically disable some member function names.

Eg:

```
static assert(!isForwardRange!(typeof(d.without!"save")));
```

Answer (score 1):

what is wrong with using [`std.variant`](http://www.d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_variant.html) which implements all you need for dynamic typing (along with quite a bit of syntactic sugar)

Comment: `std.variant` doesn't support types having arbitrary fields.

Comment: OP wants to create an object where `obj.anything` is valid at compile-time (even though it might not be valid at run-time). Nothing in `std.variant` allows this, as I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide an overload for isInputRange? Something like this (note that I haven't looked at the implementation of isInputRange):

```
template isInputRange(T : Dynamic) {
    enum isInputRange = false;
}
```

If this is provided by your dynamic.core, I think this overload should be chosen before the std lib one.

Comment: Right, but the problem is that this would require knowing every kind of prevention in advance. Obviously, it doesn't work for whoever ends up using my library...

Comment: Unfortunately this trick does not work, std.stdio can't pick up the specialization.

Answer (score 0):

For the general case Dynamic has to accept any method lookup at compile time, as you said. Suppose for a moment that you could prevent the isInputRange predicate to evaluate to true, now the wrong code will be generated when you try to create a Dynamic from an input range.

I don't think this is fixable, at least not in a general way. In this particular case the best solution I can think of is that Dynamic provides it's own version of toString, and writeln would prefer that over the inputRange specialization. I believe writeln doesn't do this at the moment, at least not for structs, but it probably should.

Another compromise would be to disallow a few methods such as popFront in the opDispatch constraint, instead Dynamic would provide opIndex or a member object to access these special cases. This might not be as bad as it sounds, because the special cases are rare and using them would result in an obvious compiler error.

I think that the best way to salvage this kind of method resolution for Dynamic is to fix writeln and accept that Dynamic will not work with all templated code.

Comment: The trouble with making writeln prefer toString over isInputRange is that every class inherits a generic toString method from Object, which just outputs the class name. Therefore, if writeln was changed, it would have to treat structs and classes differently.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into std.variant?

```d
import std.stdio, std.variant;

class Foo {
    string Bar(string a) {
        return a ~ " are Cool!";
    }
}

void main() {
    Variant foo = new Foo();
    Variant result = foo.peek!Foo.Bar("Variants");

    writeln(result); // Variants are Cool!
}
```

http://www.d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_variant.html